# XMLHttpRequest works in Adobe Air preview but not compiled app

Tags: air, xmlhttprequest

I've an adobe air app that I've been building using Dreamweaver CS5 as my IDE.  When I preview the application everything works perfectly.  When I create the app and try and run it the first XMLHttpRequest I run fails.  I'm thinking it is a security issue, but I've not clue.

I get the 'invalid' password message every time because the domainCOM.status is returning a status of 0.

UPDATE: I installed an app to watch the XMLHttpRequest and it says that I'm getting a status of 200 and I can see the correct XML being returned.  This menas that adobe air is somehow making the status of 200 into a 0.

UPDATE2: If I run it in preview I get

readyState 2, status 200
readyState 3, status 200
readyState 3, status 200
readyState 4, status 200

but if I run it in the compiled version I only get

readyState 4, status 0

Seems like it's not doing anything but I can see the actual XHR making the call and returning using Fiddler2.

Very weird.

Any help / thoughts would be appreciated.  Here's the code snippet:

```
var url = "http://open-api.domain.com/authentication.getUserToken.domain";
var vars = "v=3&appKey="+appKey+"&email="+email+"&password="+password;

var domainCOM = new XMLHttpRequest();
domainCOM.open("POST", url, true);
domainCOM.setRequestHeader ("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
domainCOM.setRequestHeader ("Content-length", vars.length);
domainCOM.setRequestHeader ("Connection", "close");         

domainCOM.onreadystatechange = function() {     
   if (domainCOM.readyState == done) {
      if (domainCOM.status == ok) {
         if (domainCOM.responseText) {
            //do some stuff
         }
         else {
            window.alert('unknown error in authenticationGetUserToken.');
         }
        }
        else {               
            window.alert('Password / Userid combination is not valid.  Please correct and try again.');
        }     
    }
};
domainCOM.send(vars);
return;
```

Thanks,
Casey

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I get a status code `0` in a web browser, it usually means I'm making a cross-domain request and the browser is simply dropping the request. Are your JS files being loaded in the [application sandbox](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7eb3.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7eb5)? Though I've not tried it yet, Air allows [cross-domain AJAX requests] in the application sandbox, but has sharply limited the cross-domain abilities of pages loaded off web servers.